# Why cant i replace another - with /?

Tags: javascript

Write a function normalize, that replaces '-' with '/' in a date string.

Example: `normalize('20-05-2017')` should return '20/05/2017'.

This is what I wrote:

```
function normalize(str) {
    let replaced = str.replace('-', '/')
    return replaced
}
```

I can't replace the other  - with / can someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `replace`, only the first instance is replaced. See [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

What you can do is either

Use [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

```js
const replaced = str.replaceAll('-', '/');
```

Or

```js
const replaced = str.replace(/-/g, '/');
```

The g means Global, and causes the replace call to replace all matches, not just the first one

Comment: Please flag duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `str.replace('-','/')` use `str.replaceAll('-','/')`